# Fresh mysql database getting "mydb.background_task doesn't exist" - Django

Tags: mysql, django, google-cloud-sql

I have a fresh install of a django app that uses background_tasks. If I remove the models that use background_task then I am able to do

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

However, if I keep them, I get a table missing exception:

```
"mydb.background_task doesn't exist"
```

I have seen other people with this issue but I have tried every single suggestion:
- delete all migrations files
- delete sqlite3 dump file
- uninstall django and django-background-tasks
- make sure my machine does not have those two packages installed even outside of the virtualenv
- I tried deleting my virtualenv and reinstalling everything.

I have tried all of these things and python manage.py makemigrations is still giving me that exception. But nothing else does that.

```
Django==2.1.5
django-background-tasks==1.2.0
django-compat==1.0.15
django-mysql==3.2.0
```

p.s: I am using Cloud SQL, I don't know if that affects anything, I don't think so. same issue with mysql

EDIT:
adding the trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 71, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 198, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 304, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 217, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'zynqdb_dev.background_task' doesn't exist")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 350, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 379, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 366, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 396, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 533, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 526, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/tesselapp/tesselapp/urls.py", line 49, in <module>
    one_time_setup_background(priority=10)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/background_task/tasks.py", line 296, in __call__
    remove_existing_tasks)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/background_task/tasks.py", line 239, in schedule
    task.save()
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/background_task/models.py", line 315, in save
    return super(Task, self).save(*arg, **kw)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 718, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 748, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 831, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 869, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1136, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1289, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 71, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 198, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 304, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/Users/cottrell/tessel/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 217, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'zynqdb_dev.background_task' doesn't exist")
```

Also I have already tried:

```
find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete
find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete
```

I have tried reinstalling and uninstalling.

Also, the same error occurs if I do python manage.py showmigrations.

Here's the part of the model where if I comment out @background it works, but with @background it doesn't work.

```
def one_time_setup():
    if settings.SENTRY_TOKEN:
        sentry_sdk.init(
            settings.SENTRY_TOKEN,
            integrations=[DjangoIntegration()]
        )


#@background()
def one_time_setup_background():
    one_time_setup()


# Do one-time setup in django app, and background with high priority.
one_time_setup()
one_time_setup_background()
```

Comment: Have you tried running `python manage.py makemigrations background_task` first, and then run `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Yes even specifying background_task for makemigrations causes the crash. It's so odd.

Comment: Can you provide the fulltraceback?  And can you show the model that throws the error?

Comment: @JonathanC Have you tried the same with Local MYSQL?

Comment: @JonathanC This is a bit of a longshot but do you have `django.contrib.admin` on your `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: @CalebGoodman, I have added the traceback and the model (well, one, there's more than one, but I can recreate the error even if I remove all of the other models. And commenting this background annotation fixes the issue (since it no longer tries to do anything with background_tasks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there is a issue in the library see https://github.com/arteria/django-background-tasks/issues/204. You may want to temporarily delete your code to migrate your database.

Comment: This was the issue, I had three static processes in total (one of them being the call to one_time_setup_background() as stated above). By only commenting those out, I was able to run makemigrations and migrate. THEN, it was safe to uncomment since that created the missing table.
It's a chicken and egg problem that at least has that workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing the following from the **[Documentation](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation):**

> **Install from PyPI**:

`pip install django-background-tasks`

> **Add to INSTALLED_APPS inside your settings.py.**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
# ...
'background_task',
# ...
)
```

> **Check that everything is fine with your migrations.**

```
python manage.py showmigrations
```

> **Migrate your database and check if the background_task file is added to the migrations list.**

`python manage.py migrate`

> **Make modifications in your views in which ever way you want to use the background_tasks. For example, you can look up a userID and send them message.**

```
from background_task import background
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

@background(schedule=60)
def notify_user(user_id):
    # lookup user by id and send them a message
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    user.email_user('Here is a notification', 'You have been notified')
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you didn't delete the contents of each `pycache` folder, which means Django will still try to reference non-existent migrations.

Here is an easy-to-use shortcut for clearing migrations, which I found from [this blog post](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html).  Just run the following from the CLI **in your root project folder**:

```
find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -not -path "./env/*" -delete
find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc" -not -path "./env/*" -delete
```

Afterwards, delete your sqlite db, and try the migrations again.

> If you run this in the wrong directory, you will break your Django download, along with any 3rd party Django apps that use migrations!

I use this frequently, so I went ahead and made it a [bash function](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias):

```
function djclear() {
  dir="${PWD##*/}"
  if [ -d $dir ]; then
       find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -not -path "./env/*" -delete
       find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc" -not -path "./env/*" -delete
  else
    echo "Returning with exit code 1. Are you sure that you are in a project directory?"
    return 1
  fi
}
```

This looks complicated, but all it really does is confirm that you are in a Django Project folder before executing the command.

Comment: If you still can't get it to work please update with the models that use `django-background-tasks` and the full traceback.

Comment: unfortunately, I had already tried these, and I manually verified that the correct files were deleted (demonstrating I was in the correct directory).